# Bash curl mail: How to upload-file with umlaut in filename?

Tags: bash, curl

I wrote a bash script that goes through a list of names finds the appropriate file based on the name and sends the text of the file as an email to the the name's email address. Everything seems to work fine except when the file name includes an umlaut or other such accent.

```
curl --ssl-reqd --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' --user 'me@gmail.com:password' --mail-from 'me@gmail.com' --mail-rcpt 'you@somewhere.com' --upload-file 'thisHasAnUmläut.txt'
```

The error I get is `curl: (56) response reading failed`. The file's text itself has nothing special in it.

Question: How should one deal with such accents in this case?

Comment: From `curl` man-page:  When uploading to an SMTP server: **the uploaded data is assumed to be RFC 5322 formatted**. It has to feature  the  necessary  set of headers and mail body formatted correctly by the user as curl will not transcode nor encode it further in any way.

Comment: @LéaGris Thank you for the reply. My issue is that the filename contains an umlaut so it isn't being found. When there is no umlaut everything works fine. Will your comment solve this problem?

Comment: If your file is not RFC 5322 formatted, curl will probably try to submit it as-is and it handles only ASCII 7-bit witch cannot handle the umlaut character.

Comment: @LéaGris I added `MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8` to the txt uploaded-file yet I get the same error.

Comment: Um, why don't you rename it?) `name=thisHasAnUmläut.txt; newname=${name//ä/a}; mv $name $newname; name=$newname`

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322 This is not MIME, although it can have MIME parts. You cannot send a raw text file like this. You have to make it into a fully structured RFC 8322 message with headers, envelope, body with enventually MIME parts. If you intend to send the file as attachment, you have to header encode its name to produce the proper MIME headers and ensure the body of your text file content is also properly encoded (Quoted-Printable, line width of max 72 characters or Base-64 encoded)... You need a Mail User Agent like `mutt` or a library, because `curl` will not do it for you